# Getting javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: Not permitted while trying to perform sender action through java code

Tags: xml, jms

```java
QueueSender queueSender = queueSession.createSender(queue);
```

My requirement is to send a XML request into TIBCO queue via Java.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately you haven't really provided enough detail in your question to provide a meaningful answer. Please elaborate on what you've tried to resolve the situation as well as the configuration of your broker (especially related to security).

Comment: Has mentioned in the previous comment you need to check the Access Rights defined for the target queue and confirm if the user you are using the connect to the EMS server has the 'send' right for the target queue

Comment: I am using the same queue,username,password details in UFT automation tool ,it is able to send the message to the queue.But this issue occurs while trying from java.

Comment: Is this something to do with Tibjmsadmin class..

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException, JMSException, IOException, TibjmsAdminException {
  InitialContext ic = getInitialContext(jndiProviderUrl);
  ApplicationMessageSender qs = new ApplicationMessageSender();
  qs.init(ic, jmsQueueName,JMS_FACTORY);
  readAndSend(qs);
  qs.close();
 }

Comment: //Settingn initial context
 public static InitialContext getInitialContext(String url) throws NamingException
 {
  Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
  env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, jmsConnectionFactory);
  env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, jndiProviderUrl);
  env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,jmsSecurityPrincipal);
  env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,jmsSecurityPassword);
  return new InitialContext(env);
 }

Comment: public void init(Context ctx, String queueName,String jmsFactory)
   throws NamingException, JMSException, TibjmsAdminException {

  qconFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup(jmsFactory);
  qcon = qconFactory.createQueueConnection();
  qsession = qcon.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

  qcon.start();
  queue = (Queue) ctx.lookup(jmsQueueName);
  qsender = qsession.createSender(queue);
  System.out.println("Queue Configured:"+qsender.getQueue().getQueueName());
  msg = qsession.createTextMessage();
 }

Comment: public void send(String message) throws JMSException {
  msg.setText(message);
  qsender.send(msg);
 }

Comment: private static void readAndSend(ApplicationMessageSender qs)throws IOException, JMSException{
  qs.send(FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(xmlRequest)).toString());
 }

Comment: is there any thing with respect to TIBCO jms services?